# @jsonRootName not working with spring boot starter hateoas

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I am developing an rest application using spring-boot and using spring-Hateoas . And the DTO that i have written is:

Bill.java

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonRootName("bills")
public class Bill{
```

Depedencies:

```
dependencies {
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-ws"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka:${springCloudVersion}"

testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
```

Application.java:

```
@Configuration
@Import(BillServiceConfig.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableEurekaClient
@ComponentScan({"com.billing"})
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = EnableHypermediaSupport.HypermediaType.HAL)
public class Application {
```

BillController.java:

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "")
 public ResponseEntity<Resources<Resource<Bill>>> getBills(@PathVariable String billUid)
```

And the spring-boot version I am using is 1.2.2. The output that I am getting is

```
`_embedded: {
BillList:
{`
```

The json Root name here is BillList. But I need it as "bills" instead of "BillList". Can anybody help out in this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The keys within an `_embedded` clause are actually relation names. Hence, they're obtained though a `RelProvider` abstraction in Spring HATEOAS. The easiest way to customize them is by annotating the domain type with `@Relation` and define the relation names that you expect for item and collection relations.

An easy way to get correct plurals used in the `_embedded` clause is by adding the Evo Inflector JAR to your classpath as documented [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/0.17.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#spis.rel-provider).

Comment: I'm looking for an example of how to use the `@Relation` annotation and the Evo Inflector JAR to get the `_embedded` clause setup  correctly in my response. Do you know of any examples that show how to do this?